# Where to put code in Google Glass quickstart for Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-mirror-api, google-glass

We've set up app engine, downloaded the python quick start, and have been able to edit the HTML page itself. We're a team so we've set up Github and all that too. However, we've got some questions as to where to place the actual code. Here's what we know so far - feel free to tell us what we're wrong about and/or give us advice and pointers. It's fine if you want to give advice in java or any other language.

- Default methods that we can use are in main_handler.py (such as
  insert item)
- When we want to write our custom code to call methods,
  where do we place this? As in what file, or are we even supported to
  insert something into the quickstart package?
- When we figure out the above, how do we send a message from Glass
  back to the server? Do we utilize the quickstart/what exactly do we
  do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a question about Glass. The quickstart app is just a Google App Engine project, using webapp2, which returns some basic responses to be shown in Glass. You should look at the [GAE/webapp2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction) and read the tutorial there.

Answer (score 1):

You are not really expected to insert something into quickstart, although you can certainly do so. It is best used as an example for how to write python to interact with Glass. So while you can make changes to quickstart yourself to experiment, your "real" Glassware may want to start fresh or start with the code you're looking to integrate with Glass.

That said, you can use various parts of quickstart to understand how things work better.

As you've noticed, `main_handler.py` gives you several examples of how to insert items.

In `main_handler.py` in the _insert_subscription() method, you can see how to subscribe to callbacks from Glass. The `notify/handler.py` code at https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python/blob/master/notify/handler.py is what actually processes the response from Glass.

Finally, if you are familiar with other languages, those might be the best ones to choose. The Mirror API has a very wide base of support, basically anything that you can run on a web application server, and you can use what you are most familiar with.